# Mas de un LineRenderer en un bucle for

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estoy desarrollando un videojuego en donde el player, tiene un selector de tiro, uno de sus selectores es una Escopeta, yo lo que quiero es que cuando disparo, me renderize un Linerenderer por cada proyectil que suelta. Me explico:

Se que suelta los 6 proyectiles que he puesto, ya que el daño por disparo que he puesto es 30, y los enemigos tienen una vida de 90 y cuando disparo con el selector de escopeta, los enemigos mueren al instante, pero sin embargo solo se ve 1 Line renderer que entiendo será el ultimo proyectil del que sale.
Y yo lo que quiero es que haga un Line Renderer por cada proyectil que dispara

```cs
public void Escopeta() {
        if (balasActuales <= 0) return;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            dispersor.transform.rotation = gunBarrelEnd.transform.rotation;
            dispersor.transform.Rotate(Random.Range(-factorDispersion, factorDispersion), Random.Range(-factorDispersion, factorDispersion), 0);

            balasActuales--;
            ammoSlider.value = balasActuales;

            timer = 0f;

            armaAudio.Play();
            armaLuz.enabled = true;
            puntoLuz.enabled = true;

            armaParticulas.Stop();
            armaParticulas.Play();

            armaLinea.enabled = true;
            armaLinea.SetPosition(0, transform.position);

            tiroRayo.origin = transform.position;
            tiroRayo.direction = transform.forward;

            
            if (Physics.Raycast(tiroRayo, out hitDisparo, rango, mascaraDisparable)) {
                vidaEnemigo enemyHealth = hitDisparo.collider.GetComponent<vidaEnemigo>();
                if (enemyHealth != null) {
                    enemyHealth.TenerDamage(damagePorTiro, hitDisparo.point);
                    imagenEnemigo.enabled = true;
                    imagenEnemigo.sprite = enemyHealth.icon;
                    vidaEnemigoSlider.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    vidaEnemigoSlider.value = enemyHealth.consigueLaVidaDelBicho();
                    StopCoroutine("OcultarVidaEnemigo");
                    StartCoroutine("OcultarVidaEnemigo");
                }
                else {
                    OcultaEnemigoUI();
                }
                armaLinea.SetPosition(1, hitDisparo.point);
            }
            else {
                armaLinea.SetPosition(1, tiroRayo.origin + tiroRayo.direction * rango);
            }
        }  
    }
```

Alguien con un poco de caridad y conocimientos podría echarme una mano?

Sea como sea, muchísimas gracias

Comment: Lo sé, que es por mí bien, intenté poner lineRenderer, y bucle, pero necesitaba algo más de experiencia para añadir esas etiquetas y solo deje c#, gracias de cualquier manera... Aver si hay suerte

Answer (score 0):

Problema arreglado, despues de darle muchas vueltas,lo que habia que hacer era, crear un array de line renderes , otro array de Ray's y un ultimo de Raycast's, hice publica el array del LIne renderers, previamente cree, 5 gameobjects vacios , y le añadi un line renderer a cada uno en el inspector, paso el codigo correcto

un saludo, espero que le sirva algun dia a alguien

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DisparoJugador : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damagePorTiro = 30;
    public float tiempoEntreBalas = 0.15f;
    public float rango = 100f;
    public Slider ammoSlider;
    public int municionMax = 100;
    public Image imagenEnemigo;
    public Slider vidaEnemigoSlider;
    public Light puntoLuz;


    public GameObject gunBarrelEnd;
    public GameObject dispersor;

    public float factorDispersion = 0.10f;



    float timer;
    Ray tiroRayo;
    RaycastHit hitDisparo;
    int mascaraDisparable;

    Ray[] tiroRayoEscopeta = new Ray[7];
    RaycastHit[] hitDisparoEscopeta = new RaycastHit[7];
    public LineRenderer[] linerenderArray = new LineRenderer[7];

    ParticleSystem armaParticulas;
    LineRenderer armaLinea;
    
    AudioSource armaAudio;
    Light armaLuz;
    float efectoDisplayTiempo = 0.2f;
    int balasActuales;
    bool escopeta = false;



    private void Awake()
    {
        mascaraDisparable = LayerMask.GetMask("Shootable");
        armaParticulas = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        armaLinea = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        linerenderArray[6] = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        armaAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        armaLuz = GetComponent<Light>();
        balasActuales = municionMax;
        StartCoroutine(CargarAmmo());
        imagenEnemigo.enabled = false;
        vidaEnemigoSlider.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    IEnumerator CargarAmmo()
    {
        float recargarTiempo = tiempoEntreBalas * 2;
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(recargarTiempo);
            if (balasActuales<municionMax)
            {
                balasActuales++;
                ammoSlider.value = balasActuales;
                
            }
        }
          
    }

    IEnumerator OcultarVidaEnemigo()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        OcultaEnemigoUI();
    }

    void OcultaEnemigoUI()
    {
        imagenEnemigo.enabled = false;
        vidaEnemigoSlider.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        SwitchWeapon();

        if (Input.GetButton ("Fire1")  && timer >= tiempoEntreBalas && Time.timeScale !=0 && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(-1) && escopeta == false)
        {
            Dispara();
        }
        else if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && timer >= tiempoEntreBalas && Time.timeScale != 0 && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(-1) && escopeta == true)
        {
            Escopeta();
        }
        if (timer>= tiempoEntreBalas * efectoDisplayTiempo)
        {
            ApagarEfectos();
        }
    }
    
    void Dispara()
    {

        if (balasActuales <= 0) return;

        balasActuales--;
        ammoSlider.value = balasActuales;

        timer = 0f;


        armaAudio.Play();
        armaLuz.enabled = true;
        puntoLuz.enabled = true;

        armaParticulas.Stop();
        armaParticulas.Play();

        armaLinea.enabled = true;
        armaLinea.SetPosition(0, transform.position);

        tiroRayo.origin = transform.position;
        tiroRayo.direction = transform.forward;

        dispersor.transform.rotation = gunBarrelEnd.transform.rotation;
        dispersor.transform.Rotate(Random.Range(-factorDispersion, factorDispersion), Random.Range(-factorDispersion, factorDispersion), 0);

        if (Physics.Raycast(tiroRayo,out hitDisparo,rango,mascaraDisparable))
        {
            vidaEnemigo enemyHealth = hitDisparo.collider.GetComponent<vidaEnemigo>();
            if (enemyHealth!=null)
            {
                enemyHealth.TenerDamage(damagePorTiro, hitDisparo.point);
                imagenEnemigo.enabled = true;
                imagenEnemigo.sprite = enemyHealth.icon;
                vidaEnemigoSlider.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                vidaEnemigoSlider.value = enemyHealth.consigueLaVidaDelBicho();
                StopCoroutine("OcultarVidaEnemigo");
                StartCoroutine("OcultarVidaEnemigo");
            }
            else
            {
                OcultaEnemigoUI();
            }
            armaLinea.SetPosition(1, hitDisparo.point);
        }
        else
        {
            armaLinea.SetPosition(1, tiroRayo.origin + tiroRayo.direction * rango);
        }
    }

   


    void SwitchWeapon()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("1"))
        {
            //fusil
            escopeta = false;
            damagePorTiro = 30;
            tiempoEntreBalas = 0.15f;
            rango = 50;
            factorDispersion = 1f;
            efectoDisplayTiempo = 0.2f;
            efectoDisplayTiempo = efectoDisplayTiempo * 2;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("2"))
        {
            //Escopeta
            escopeta = true;
            damagePorTiro = 30;
            tiempoEntreBalas = 0.8f;
            rango = 8;
            factorDispersion = 7f;
            efectoDisplayTiempo = 0.2f;
            efectoDisplayTiempo = efectoDisplayTiempo / 2 ;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("3"))
        {
            //Sniper
            escopeta = false;
            damagePorTiro = 210;
            tiempoEntreBalas = 1.5f;
            rango = 100;
            factorDispersion = 0f;
            efectoDisplayTiempo = 0.2f;
            efectoDisplayTiempo = efectoDisplayTiempo / 4;
        }
    }

    public void Escopeta()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            dispersor.transform.rotation = gunBarrelEnd.transform.rotation;
            dispersor.transform.Rotate(Random.Range(-factorDispersion, factorDispersion), Random.Range(-factorDispersion, factorDispersion), 0);

            linerenderArray[i] = linerenderArray[i];

            if (balasActuales <= 0) return;

            balasActuales--;
            ammoSlider.value = balasActuales;

            timer = 0f;

            armaAudio.Play();
            armaLuz.enabled = true;
            puntoLuz.enabled = true;

            armaParticulas.Stop();
            armaParticulas.Play();

            //armaLinea.enabled = true;
            //armaLinea.SetPosition(0, transform.position);

            linerenderArray[i].enabled = true;
            linerenderArray[i].SetPosition(0, transform.position);

            tiroRayoEscopeta[i].origin = transform.position;
            tiroRayoEscopeta[i].direction = transform.forward;
            
            
            if (Physics.Raycast(tiroRayoEscopeta[i], out hitDisparoEscopeta[i], rango, mascaraDisparable))
            {
                vidaEnemigo enemyHealth = hitDisparoEscopeta[i].collider.GetComponent<vidaEnemigo>();
                if (enemyHealth != null)
                {
                    enemyHealth.TenerDamage(damagePorTiro, hitDisparoEscopeta[6].point);
                    imagenEnemigo.enabled = true;
                    imagenEnemigo.sprite = enemyHealth.icon;
                    vidaEnemigoSlider.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    vidaEnemigoSlider.value = enemyHealth.consigueLaVidaDelBicho();
                    StopCoroutine("OcultarVidaEnemigo");
                    StartCoroutine("OcultarVidaEnemigo");
                }
                else
                {
                    OcultaEnemigoUI();
                }
                //armaLinea.SetPosition(1, hitDisparo.point);
                linerenderArray[i].SetPosition(1, hitDisparoEscopeta[i].point);
            }
            else
            {
                linerenderArray[i].SetPosition(1, tiroRayoEscopeta[i].origin + tiroRayoEscopeta[i].direction * rango);
                
            }
        }
        
    }

    

   public void ApagarEfectos()
    {
        
        linerenderArray[0].enabled = false;
        linerenderArray[1].enabled = false;
        linerenderArray[2].enabled = false;
        linerenderArray[3].enabled = false;
        linerenderArray[4].enabled = false;
        linerenderArray[5].enabled = false;

        armaLinea.enabled = false;
        armaLuz.enabled = false;
        puntoLuz.enabled = false;
    }

}
```